# VS 2010 database projects and tables created by "select into"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I am trying to move an existing database into a VS 2010 database project.  This database has been around for a very long time and has a lot of stored procedures.  Many of those stored procedures create working tables using the SELECT ... INTO syntax.  This was done at the time to reduce the amount of data going through the transaction log.  When I import the database into the project I deselected the work tables.  Now when I look out the warning I see all of my stored procedures are saying that they can't find the work tables.  Does anyone have a way of dealing with this?  I am slowing converting as much as I can to SSIS but there is some logic that will have to remind in the stored procedures.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you either have to ignore the warnings or import those working tables that are absolutely required for the stored procedures to work. I don't think the project will build properly if the tables are not present, but are expected.

If those tables are already present in the database, you should be fine as they won't be re-created. You can slowly deprecate them as you clean up your stored procedures.